# Show-Hide divs using jquery in a dropdown with a twist

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I want to show/hide elements depending on what is selected in the dropdown menu, I got it, but I want divs to show when either DIVAREA2 or DIVAREA3 is selected. Say, I want DIV area 4 to show in DiV area 2 & DIV area 3

Supplied a fiddle with some code from here I found that is close to what I want to do. Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ayeblinken/guDsm/1/

HTML

```
<form>
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="0">Choose</option>
<option value="area1">DIV Area 1</option>
<option value="area2">DIV Area 2</option>
<option value="area3">DIV Area 3</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="divarea1" class="box">DIV Area 1</div>
<div id="divarea2" class="box">DIV Area 2</div>
<div id="divarea3" class="box">DIV Area 3</div>
<div id="divarea4" class="box">DIV Area 4</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.box').hide();
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
$('.box').hide();
$('#div' + $(this).val().show();
});
});
```

Comment: so if you choose `DIV Area 2` or `DIV Area 3`, it will show `DIV Area 4` as well with that particular DIV selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wan more than one shown, use a class like the following:

```
<form>
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="0">Choose</option>
<option value="area1">DIV Area 1</option>
<option value="area2">DIV Area 2</option>
<option value="area3">DIV Area 3</option>
</select>
</form>
<div class="box area1">DIV Area 1</div>
<div class="box area1">DIV Area 2</div>
<div class="box area2">DIV Area 3</div>
<div class="box area2">DIV Area 4</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
});
```

Here is a JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mac1175/yEJL2/

### EDIT

To select area1 by default, add the `selected` attribute to your option for area 1.  The add a chained  trigger call to your change event handler like...

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 }).trigger('change');
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mac1175/FKf9p/

Comment: Cool, thanks mitch! Code I uploaded was just some example code, what I am working on is complicated. I originally tried to do what you showed me, I must have had some typo somewhere, I will try again, at least I know I am on the right track. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hey mitch, if you don't mind, do you know how I would code it so that when you first go to the page you don't have to choose, it will be on DIV Area 1 by default?

Comment: Thanks again Mitch, I actually figured(found) a solution. I already had id's on the ones I wanted to show, so I used `$('.box:not(#pressTick)').hide();`   I saved your edit too, easier! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about an if statement?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.box').hide();
   $('#dropdown').change(function() {
      var area = $(this).val();
      $('.box').hide();
      $('#div' + area).show();
        if(area == 'area2' || area== 'area3') {
          $('#divarea4').show();
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Barbara! I like the more compact code from mitch, but I will keep this in mind though.